# How can I import blueprint to main py in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to make flask blueprint structure with MongoDB

I could not load blueprint from another package.

my project structure like this

[image]

Project/app.py :
I initialize app and try to regist blueprint

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from Home.home import home_bp ## error: Unable import Home.home

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'data'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/data'

mongo = PyMongo(app)

app.register_blueprint(home_bp, url_prefix='/home')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Project/Home/home.py:

```
from flask import jsonify, request, Blueprint
from ..app import mongo # error: attempted relative import beyond-toplevel

home_bp = Blueprint('home', __name__)

@ home_bp.route('home/geoitems', methods=['GET'])
def get_all_geoitems():
    geoitems = mongo.db.geoitems
    output = []
    for s in geoitems.find():
        output.append(
            {'type': s['type'], 'lat': s['lat'], 'long': s['long']})
    # print(output)
    return jsonify({'result': output})
```

Comment: `from .Home import home` ... `app.register_blueprint(home.home_bp, url_prefix='/home')` could work

Comment: @ Kruspe I tried but I can see that error :  Attempted relative import beyond top-level package